# Maven can't download its plugin (as clean), can this situation depend by a proxy configuration issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ide, maven-plugin

I am not so into Maven and I have the following problem:

I have download a project (that use **Spring**) from the SVN repository of my company and there are some building errors that seems depends by the fact that some dependencies are missing (for example all the Spring dependencies).

So I tried to select the project and do a **Run as ---> Maven Clean** as first step before building the project (also if it should perform the clean before the build if I do **Maven build** but this is not important at this stage) and I obtain this error message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GestioneUtenzeCloud 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://srvabc02.soft.it:8888/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://srvabc02.soft.it:8888/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.561 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-19T12:35:43+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://srvabc02.soft.it:8888/artifactory/plugins-release): srvabc02.soft.it: Unknown host srvabc02.soft.it -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

So it seems that it can't download the Maven plugin (in this case the clean plugin).

My computer is connected to Internet passing through the company **proxy** so I think that is can not download the Maven plugin because the proxy is not configured on my Eclipse...is it possible? What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Check this:  ` srvabc02.soft.it: Unknown host srvabc02.soft.it` Your settings.xml is wrong. Furthermore i would recommend to check such things from command line and not within Eclipse.

Comment: I had the same problem with Eclipse Mars. It could not download artifact and it was because of my proxy (I even tried to manually add the proxy and still nothing). What I've done is I downgraded to Eclipse Luna which is "AUTO" at proxy and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. I have added the Maven proxy settings into the **settings.xml** file that is into the **.m2** directory.

As explained here on the official documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: What proxy did you set? These stupid tutorials don't provide the proxies that I can use.